# How to set the initial value of a select created using ng-options with an Object as the value in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a form used to update a record populated from a restful service.

One of the fields uses a select for a look-up value and I'm binding it to an object in my model.

The select is created correctly and choosing options makes the correct changes to my model.

The problem is when I initially load the page the select is blank.

Is there a way to set the initial value correctly without having to crawl the look-up object and match the id to get the auto-generated index position?

Or better yet, set the value to be the object instead of an auto-generated index.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    Id: <input ng-model="course.id" readonly><br>
    Cost: <input ng-model="course.cost" ng-required="true"><br>
    Title: <select ng-model="course.courseTitle" ng-options="title.name for title in courseTitles">
      </select> {{course.courseTitle.description}}<br>
    Length: <input ng-model="course.length" ng-required="true"><br>
    <br>
    Id: {{course.id}}<br>
    Cost: {{course.cost}}<br>
    Title: {{course.courseTitle.name}}<br>
    Length: {{course.length}}
</div>

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.course = {
        "id": "108",
        "cost": "155",
        "courseTitle": {
            "description": "Description of course 37.",
            "id": "37",
            "name": "Course 37 Name"
        },
        "length": "7"
    };

    $scope.courseTitles = [{
        "description": "Description of course 37.",
        "id": "37",
        "name": "Course 37 Name"},
    {
        "description": "Description of course 63.",
        "id": "67",
        "name": "Course 63 Name"},
    {
        "description": "Description of course 88.",
        "id": "88",
        "name": "Course 88 Name"}];

}
```

I have created a fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/bcarter/Jxydp/

Comment: The data for both objects is loaded from a restful service.  I only defined it in the controller of this example to get the fiddle to work.  Getting the service changed is not really an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have two different objects you're working with here. You have

```
    {
        "description": "Description of course 37.",
        "id": "37",
        "name": "Course 37 Name"
    }
```

defined twice, creating two different references. If you use the same object, it will work as expected. See http://jsfiddle.net/Jxydp/14/ (There's probably a better way of doing it, but it illustrates my point)

Comment: I kinda figured it was being caused because it's two different objects.  So maybe a little different question down this path.  Is there an easy way to make them reference the same object?  What I'm trying to avoid is what I've done in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bcarter/Jxydp/  I tried to get the commented filter option to work but I cant figure that out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with that commented out code, but I don't see a problem with the for loop to get the correct object. Be aware that angular does provide it's own forEach (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.forEach) that makes the looping easier.

Comment: looks like I pasted the wrong thing in the comment.  I found an example using angular.Array.filter([array object],{[filter]}) that I couldn't get to work.  $scope.course.courseTitle = angular.Array.filter($scope.courseTitles,{id:$scope.course.courseTitle.id});  Basically, I was hoping to just have an easy search of the array.  I still don't understand how angular is comparing the two objects during the initialization.  It would be nice to override that with if (id===id).

Comment: I'm not familiar with any kind of Array filter thing. The bottom line is you need to tell angular what your model is. In the original example, the object did not === any object in the ng-options, and so it added the blank option. You can loop through to find the object you want, or you could restructure your data to be an object instead of an array and key off the ids like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jxydp/63/.

Answer (score 5):

Use the "track by" clause of ng-options

```
<select ng-model="course.courseTitle" 
        ng-options="title.name for title in courseTitles track by title.id">
</select>
```

This will cause the comparison to do the check by title.id == other.id instead of title == other

Comment: This answer is actually the way to deal with the "reference" issue. Thank you Marc!

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little opinionated, but I think it'd be better to change the structure your data. Just have an array with your models

```
$scope.courses = [{
    "cost": "155",
    "description": "Description of course 37.",
    "id": "37",
    "name": "Course 37 Name",
    "length": "8"
},{
    "cost": "156",
    "description": "Description of course 63.",
    "id": "67",
    "name": "Course 63 Name",
    "length": "9"        
},{
    "cost": "157",
    "description": "Description of course 88.",
    "id": "88",
    "name": "Course 88 Name",
    "length": "9"        
}];
```

Then change both `ngModel` and `ngOptions` in your `select` element to

```
<select ng-model="course" ng-options="course.name for course in courses">
```

And then in your controller tell angular to set whatever course in your courses as the initial one

```
$scope.course = $scope.courses[0];
```

This way you don't need to worry about another object and to keep things in sync, let angular do it for you.

JSfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/jaimem/uuCfx/1/